# Constant max date measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have date table with all dates day by day related with salesdata table with sctructure basically like:
**region, branch, user, date, product, saleVolume**
So multiple dates per user.
I have also date slicer in report page.
I am in need of a measure, that will give constant max date depending on slicer selection and slicer selection only. For every possible combination of row/column in matrix visualisation - I want the same max date in every cell. Every combination of calculate(max/lastdate(),all/allselected/removefilter()) I tried resulted in giving max date per region/branch/user in data table, so if I select 01.01 - 10.01 range in slicer, but user's last sale was 05.01, the measure returns 05.01 instead of 10.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something simple like:

```
Max Slicer Date :=
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) ,
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Date', 'Date'[Date] )
)
```

Edit: Here is some sample data that shows this is exactly what the measure does:

[image]

Edit 2: If you are for some reason using a bidirectional relationship between `'Date'[Date]` and `'Sales'[Date]` (not sure why one would do that in the first place, it is not a good idea and I strongly recommend avoiding such modeling philosophies) then you can amend the measure like so:

```
Max Slicer Date :=
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) ,
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Date', 'Date'[Date] ) ,
    CROSSFILTER ( 'Date'[Date] , 'Sales'[Date] , NONE )
)
```

Comment: If you meant CALCULATE( MAX('Date'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Date','Date'[Date])), then no - it gives the wrong result.

Comment: What date column are you using for your slicer?

Comment: 'Date'[Date], from date table, not 'Sales'[Date].

Comment: Then I am out of ideas as to why this simple measure does not return a correct value. Are you using 'Date'[Date] as a dimension in the matrix?

Comment: No, the matrix is region/branch/user X product. As I said - it takes max date from 'Sales'[Date] for specific region/branch/user, not 'Date'[Date] as I want. I mean, the two are connected with relatonship, but It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Are you using bidirectional filtering for your 'Date'[Date] - 'Sales'[Date] relationship?

Comment: Yes, I'm retarded, how did you know? :D 
No idea why it was there.

Comment: Ahh excellent! It was the only thing left that could potentially cause this issue, but I must admit I didn't really factor in bi-directional relationship since it's a bit unconventional when used with date tables!

Comment: Yeah, I know it's bad thing. Maybe I set it to bidirectional when trying to figure out previous problem and forgot to uncheck it. Thanks anyway so much!